# How to handle liquidity pool transfers and fees?

Tags: contract-development, fees, liquidity, tokenomics

Suppose I have a token on the Ethereum network. From what I understand, with each buy and sell a part of the transaction is maintained by the contract that adds it to the LP (liquidity pool). However, the fees can be high compared to the transaction itself, which could easily make the contract pay, say, something equivalent to 10 USD in fees just to add something equivalent to 5 USD to the LP. In other words, the contract is punishable for small buys and sells. How do developers usually deal with this?

Thank you!